# Position image overlay based on the dimensions of parent div

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, overlay, dimensions

I have an animated image overlay which I am trying to position based on the height of the overlays parent div. The dimensions of the parent div are created dynamically.

The code which I am currently using:

```
jQuery('.parentdiv').hover(function(){
jQuery(".overlaydiv", this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.95", top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
}, function() {
jQuery(".overlaydiv", this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.95", top: '185px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
});
```

What I am wanting to know is how can I calculate the height of the outer div and then apply it to my existing code. Specifically, I need to replace the 185px with whatever the parent divs height is at the time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$(this).outerHeight(true)` should give you the height of the parent div, but that would just place the overlay div at that location as you are setting `top: $(this).outerHeight(true)` Is that is what you want?

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work. Replaced the 185px with your code but my jQuery is not the best. Should I be adding something else? The overlay function is a slide up/slide down effect hence the need to specify a height on the second main line of code so that it pushes itself back down again on mouseoff.

Answer (score 0):

Try `outerHeight()` in JQuery ([Source](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)):

```
top: $(this).outerHeight(true) //specfiy true because we want to include margins
```

**Edit: Although, if you're wanting to place the child *after* the parent vertically, try:**

```
top: $(this).outerHeight(true) + $(this).position().top
```

Comment: This may not give him the desired effect. See my comment above

Comment: Ahh yeah, I think he may be confusing what he means now you mention it, the code above will give him the parent's height, but he probably wants to add that to `$(this).position().top` I'll edit to include.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I can't seem to get this to work with the existing code.

Comment: If I replace the 185px with the code it slides up but just stays there instead of sliding back down on mouseoff.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to reverse both the 0 and other value? If you want to slide it down on hover, then back up on mouseout that's what you'd need to do?

Comment: I need it the other way around, slide up on hover and then slide back down. The slide up part works fine. I need jQuery to calculate the height of 'parentdiv' and then replace the 185px with the parent div height.

Comment: @cknz Can you provide the markup? I'll give you a working example in JSFiddle :)

Comment: It is within a cms so difficult to emulate with just the markup as many elements are applied dynamically etc.